# Init block vs. constructor chaining

Tags: java

Which runs first, init block or `this()` (in case of constructor chaining) in Java?

I searched and found that `this()` has higher priority than constructor chaining but I when I tried to run output was different

```
class Init_block {
    {
        //init block   
        System.out.println("This is init block");
    }

    Init_block() {
        this(10);
        System.out.println("First constructor");
    }

    Init_block(int a) {
        System.out.println("Second constructor" + " " + a);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new Init_block();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: add your code in question.

Comment: @PrateekKapoor Never put code in comments. If you are asked to provide more information; simply **edit** your question and add stuff there. That also allows for real formatting of your code.

Answer (score 1):

whenever child class constructor is called, all base class will be loaded First starting from immediate base class till Object class. after loading all the classes till `Object` class, constructor will be executed starting from `Object` class to `child class`.

but before executing child class constructor , init block will be executed first of child class.

if multiple init blocks are present then they will be executed in order of appearance.
after executing all init blocks compiler will finally execute constructor of child class.

in your case 
firstly `Init_block()` will be called but `Object` class constructor will be executed first.

then `Init_block class's init block` will be executed.
after executing init block JVM will execute constructor. as in constructor you are calling parameterized constructor as `this(10)` so jvm will execute

```
Init_block(int a)
```

after executing parameterized constructor control will be return to no-arg constructor and rest of the lines will be executed.

Comment: I und that is what happening .i was just wondering that priority goes like super() then this()  followed by init block hence in this case  super is followed by init block then constructor chaining is achieved.The above prg dsnt follow the sequence

Comment: @PrateekKapoor here also same thing is happening. because in Object class No-arg constructor doesn't have anything that is why you are not getting any output but that will be executed first than your init block.